Camera2 control torch strength
Im playing around with the camera2Video sample (https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video), and I want to be able to control not just the torch on/off, but also its strength/intensity.
So far, I've only been able to toggle the flash, but I cannot find any documentation for the strength (most deal with CameraX).
session.device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD).apply {
    set(
        CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
        if (torch) CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH else CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF
    )
}

I tried utilizing the camera manager
//session.setRepeatingRequest(recordRequest(torch = true), sessionListener, cameraHandler)
cameraManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(camera.id, 2)


but it throws an error
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel:2958: 
Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user


Flash brightness control while the camera is open is just added to Android 15, which is still in beta, so it's not very available in the wild yet.
Once Android 15 is launched, control is likely available at least on Pixel devices.
